# Manga about a female lead with healing powers who teams up with a prince to get revenge on her best friend and the church

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic

What’s the name of the full color manga with a female lead who is a healer and is wronged by her friend -- who is also a healer -- and wants to get revenge on her?

It turns out her friend is working with the priest and is letting monsters into the village so that they would be in power. The female lead teams up with the prince to get revenge on the best friend and the church.

It turns out the female lead's powers are different from other healers. She absorbs the wounds herself and then heals herself. The female leads hair turns from blonde to white and the prince's hair is blond.

The best friend steals the knight that she had a crush on.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: It was in full color

Answer (score 2):

This matches the synopsis of [Vengeance From A Saint Full of Wounds](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/l4ni7wz/kizu-darake-seijo-yori-houfuku-wo-komete): (emphasis mine)

> Lua is a saintess candidate who possesses the power of healing. But her ability had one flaw: **she could only heal others by transferring their wounds onto herself**. Because of this, others bullied her, calling her the "Fallen Saintess." But it didn't bother Lua because her best friend Arianne always stood up for her.
>
> One day, Lua's crush, Commander Garrett, was on the brink of death from a beast attack. Lua healed him, which left her on the verge of death. **When she woke up, she learned that all the credit was given to Arianne, and she finally saw her best friend's true color.** Devastated, Lua is lost and helpless when the second prince appears in front of her with a tempting offer. What would happen to Lua as she begins her new life as a villainess?

The first two chapters show her best friend stealing the knight, the main character's hair changing from blonde to white, her swearing to never save people again (and hurting one by transferring wounds) and ends with the blonde prince looking at her.